# I want to fill a 2-dimensional array of pointers with strings

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, type-2-dimension

I'm a little desperate because it's for a school exercise. I am requested to fill a 50x7 array with strings so that they are saved for further use , like a data base for a bank system. So i need to scan some strings and save them on that array. I need to use pointers , so i need an array of pointers that can contain whatever i scan , but whenever i try something it keeps crashing after my first scan and i cannot fill it correctly. It's probably a syntax error. Please show me how can i fill a 2-dim array of pointers.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    int i, j;

    char save[50][7];
    char* ptr[50][7];

    for(i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 7; j++)
        {
            ptr[i][j] = &save[i][j];
        }
    }

    for(i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < 2; j++)
        {
            scanf("%s", ptr[i][j]);
        }
    }

    for(i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < 2; j++)
        {
            printf("%s", ptr[i][j]);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please post your efforts .

Comment: What code have you written?

Comment: Please show us your efforts(the code), so we can help you

Comment: Crashes? this: `char *save[2[4];` wont even compile?

Comment: You have not allocated any memory for your pointer array.

Comment: sry it wasnt like this it was ok

Comment: how do i do this @WeatherVane

Comment: @WeatherVane unfortunatelly i am not allowed because we didnt learn that so far

Comment: I can't even see a 50 or a 7 in there, even allowing for the typo in `char *save[2[4];`

Comment: @WeatherVane i made it smaller so i can fill it faster

Comment: So if it's not 50x7, what is it? You still haven't corrected the typo pointed out earlier.

Comment: I'm not sure how they expect you to use a pointer array without using `malloc`. You could have a `char[350][MAX_LINE]` array and set each of your pointers to the address of one of these, but I doubt that's really what the teacher wants.

Comment: @WeatherVane  i changed the code above , now it doesnt crash but if i.e. i put " a 
b 
c 
d " it prints "a bb c dd " why is that ?

Comment: Seeing as your `scanf` loop is two-dimensioinal, I am so sorry, but it is still not even clear whether you want 50 strings of length 7 (in which case the `[7]` should be an `[8]` to include the string terminator) or 350 strings of unknown length.

Comment: @WeatherVane i just need a 50X7 array of pointers so that i can "save" strings on each pointer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define e.g. `char save[50][7][256]` to have 50*7 string arrays of max 255 chars. With your definition you have 50*7 array of single chars. Change `save` definition plus the line `ptr[i][j] = &save[i][j]` to `ptr[i][j] = save[i][j]`.

Comment: A `char [256] will have 256 `char`s. It is just one entry is required for the terminator, but that still is part of the "string" (because that actually makes a sequence/an array of characters a string in C).